# Execute function after connect to database

Tags: php, mysql, function

I have a problem, I'm trying to do functions who can execute SQL syntax, but when I'm trying to execute it mysqli_query causes an error, because this function needs two parameters. But I have another function to connect to database, how can I fix this problem?

```
function connect_to_database($servername, $username,$password,$dbname) {
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
}
    
function execute($get_sql) {
    $sql[0] = $get_sql;
    mysqli_query($sql[0]);
}
    
connect_to_database("localhost","root","root","m1_14");
execute("INSERT INTO teszt_1 (email,username,order,createdate) VALUES ('test@gmail.com','test','test',NOW())");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this :

`mysqli_query` need two parameters and you give only once, so give yout `execute` function all the parameters for `mysqli_query` function

```
function connect_to_database($servername, $username,$password,$dbname) {
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    //return connection or define connection as global and use as global scenario
    return $conn;
}

function execute($get_sql, $connect) {
    $sql[0] = $get_sql;
    mysqli_query($connect, $sql[0]);
}

$connection = connect_to_database("localhost","root","root","m1_14");
execute("INSERT INTO teszt_1 (email,username,order,createdate) VALUES ('test@gmail.com','test','test',NOW())", $connection);
```

Comment: You should return the connection... or use as global as i have commented in your post

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare variables "global" :

```
<?php
    $conn = null; // ◄■■■
    $result = null; // ◄■■■

    function connect_to_database($servername, $username,$password,$dbname)
    { global $conn; // ◄■■■
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        if ($conn->connect_error)
        {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
    }

    function execute($get_sql)
    { global $conn; // ◄■■■
      global $result; // ◄■■■
        $sql[0] = $get_sql;
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql[0]); // ◄■■■ $CONN AND $RESULT.
    }

    connect_to_database("localhost","root","root","m1_14");
     execute("INSERT INTO teszt_1 (email,username,order,createdate) " .
             "VALUES ('test@gmail.com','test','test',NOW())");

    execute("select * from teszt_1");

    foreach ( $result as $row ) // ◄■■■ USE $RESULT HERE.
      echo $row["email"];
```

Global variables let you pass values from one function to another.

In case of a "insert" you don't need `$result`, in case of a "select" you can use `$result` to access the values.

Comment: yeah but cant he do by returning simply connection variable from his first method (connection method) ?

Comment: @ShaileshSingh, there's more than one way to skin a cat.

Comment: @FaragoRoland, in case you execute a "select" you will need the result.